# Jquery change elements values?

Tags: jquery

I have 5 divs.

```
<div class="wx-temp">89 <sup>°F</sup></div>
<div class="wx-temp">91 <sup>°F</sup></div>
<div class="wx-temp">87 <sup>°F</sup></div>
<div class="wx-temp">90 <sup>°F</sup></div>
<div class="wx-temp">89 <sup>°F</sup></div>
```

I get them like this.

```
var degress = $("div.wx-temp").text();
```

I want to append celcius values after the `sup` elements.

When I get the degress in `.each` function it parse the text like this:

```
{8,9,°,F,9,1,°,F.........}
```

I want to get only integers like this:

```
{89,91,87,90,89}
```

How can I do this?  THANKS.

Comment: Why did you downvote. If you explain, You will help me for asking quality questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're iterating over `.text`, that's what you'll get – an iteration over each character in the string. You want to iterate over the entire list of elements:

```
$("div.wx-temp").each(function() {
    var degFahrenheit = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    var degCelcius = customConversionHere(degFahrenheit);
    // append degCelcius to $(this)
});
```

Strictly, `$(this).text()` above will yield `"89 °F"`, rather than `"89"`, but `parseInt` will take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var degress = $("div.wx-temp").text();
var substr = degrees.split(' °F');
```

gives

```
substr[0] = '89';
substr[1] = '91';
```

Comment: No, it yields `["89 ", "F91 ", ...]`

Comment: Better! Throw in an extra space, `.split(' °F')`, and you'll remove that from the output as well. You'll still have some residue at the end of the array, though. You might want to add `substr.pop()` after the operation, to remove the last empty slot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    alert(GiveDegrees());

});

function GiveDegrees()
{
    var divs = $('div.wx-temp');
    var degrees = new Array();

    $.each(divs,function(i,j){

        degrees.push( stringToNum( $(this).text()));

    });

    return degrees;
}

function stringToNum(str){
  return str.match(/\d+/g);

}
```

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/LyG6q/5/